# Understanding flex-grow and flex-shrink when using flex-basis

Tags: css, flexbox, percentage

I'm trying to understand the following line.

`flex: 0 1 50%`

Now if the last value, flex basis was pixels the above would say that the item is not allowed to grow, but allowed to shrink and will be at maximum 50 pixels.

But with percentage in there instead, what are the relations. It will be maximum 50% of width, but eh, since it is not allowed to grow it will stay at 50 percent of...something

Curious what your interpretation is.

Thanks in advance, as we say in Sweden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Percentage lengths are relative to their containing blocks.

Therefore, if the flex container has a width of 200px, and the flex items are set to `flex-basis: 50%`, then each item will resolve to 100px.

Of course, in flex layout, `flex-basis` represents the *initial main size* or, the size before `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` are applied.

You have `flex-grow` disabled, so nothing happens there.

But you have `flex-shrink` enabled, so the items will shrink below 100px when necessary to prevent an overflow of the container.

In this case, because all items are set to `flex-shrink: 1`, they will shrink in equal proportion.

```css
article {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

[one] > section {
  flex: 0 1 50px;
}

[two] > section {
  flex: 0 1 50%;
}

[three] > section {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}


/* non-essential demo styles */
section {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<p>container width 200px in all cases</p>
<article one>
  <section><span>50px</span></section>
  <section><span>50px</span></section>
  <section><span>50px</span></section>
  <section><span>50px</span></section>
</article>

<hr>

<p><code>flex-shrink</code> enabled</p>

<article two>
  <section><span>50%</span></section>
  <section><span>50%</span></section>
  <section><span>50%</span></section>
  <section><span>50%</span></section>
</article>

<hr>

<p><code>flex-shrink</code> disabled</p>

<article three>
  <section><span>50%</span></section>
  <section><span>50%</span></section>
  <section><span>50%</span></section>
  <section><span>50%</span></section>
</article>
```

More details about percentages and `flex-basis`:

> [§ 7.2.3. The `flex-basis`
>   property](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#flex-basis-property)
>
> Percentage values of `flex-basis` are resolved against the flex item’s
>   containing block (i.e. its flex container); and if that containing
>   block’s size is indefinite, the used value for `flex-basis` is
>   `content`.

More details about percentage lengths in general:

- [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)

Comment: I think I clearly understand now. I was confused about the interrelation and you really clarified that. Great.